# Can't import serial in VSCode

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pyserial

> import serial
> Yellow line underneath "serial".

When I hover my cursor it says 2 things:

> "serial" is not accessed Pylance
> Import "serial" could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports)

I have installed Python on the OS and VSCode.

Tried this in the terminal with no success:

> python -m pip install pyserial

returns:

> Requirement already satisfied: pyserial in c:\users...

I installed python through the .exe from python.org and installed pyserial through terminal, as well as the python and pylance extensions in VSCode, but still get the above problems.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: You have two (or more) versions of Python installed on your system.  `pip` installed the package for one version of Python, but VS Code is using a different version.

Comment: @JohnGordon You were right. I switched python interpreters in VSCode and works now. Thanks. For anyone else with this problem: Type "Python: Select Interpreter" in the Command Palette change the interpreter (the recommended one worked for me).